# Setting up IonCube on IIS7 : Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, ioncube

we've inherited a PHP project from a client that requires [IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com). Our boxes all run on IIS7 and although we've followed the instructions for configuring it, it isn't loading the decoder library. Have any of you had any success with getting IonCube up and running on Win 2k8 (32bit)?

Comment: +1 for following up with the solution to your problem to help people in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone attempting to do this in the future, here is what you must do:

1. Verify if you are running a thread-safe version of PHP (you can check that by accessing your php_info or the file they provide). If you are not running a threadsafe version continue:
2. Download the non-ts version (non-threadsafe version) from the typical download page (there are two version available)
3. Put the Dlls inside of your Windows\System folder (i put mine in a subfolder)
4. Add the line zend_extension = C:\Windows\System32\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.2.dll 
   **note that it is NOT zend_extension_ts and is zend_extension instead**
5. restart IIS
6. Run their ioncube-loader-helper.php file to verify that it worked properly.

Enjoy.